# Pointing to a variable using pointers in c-segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I wanted the pointer p to point to the value of (var-1).Please suggest a way to solve this error.

```
  int var = 10;
  int *p;
  *p =var-1;
  printf("%d",*p);
```

Comment: You can't. `*p` should point to some integer, so you can't have `var` equal to 10 and `*p` to 9.

Comment: Are you expecting it to print 9?  If so, that's not how pointers work.

Comment: Yes @dbush this is what my teacher's note is showing.How should I modify Line 3?

Comment: If the value produced by the expression `var-1` isn't stored anywhere, you can't have a pointer point to it!

Comment: Then you probably misunderstand what the teacher is asking for.

Comment: Since p is not initialized, any use of *p is incorrect;

Comment: A pointer cannot point to a *value*, a pointer points to an *object*, and at any instance an object can have a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To point to the value of the expression `(var-1)` you need an object that will store the value.

So the only approach provided that the variable `var` itself shall not be changed is the following

```
  int var = 10;
  int var2 = var-1;
  int *p = &var2;
  printf("%d",*p);
```

Or you could allocate an object of the type int dynamically where the result of the expression will be stored like

```
  int var = 10;
  int *p = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
  *p = var-1;
  printf("%d",*p);
  //...
  free( p );
```

According to the C Standard (6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators)

> 1 **The operand of the unary & operator shall be** either a function
> designator, the result of a [] or unary * operator, or **an lvalue
> that designates an object** that is not a bit-field and is not
> declared with the register storage-class specifier.

And

> 4 The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a
> function, the result is a function designator; **if it points to an
> object, the result is an lvalue designating the object.** If the operand
> has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’. If an
> invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the
> unary * operator is  undefined.

In the original code snippet you got a segmentation fault because the pointer `p` does not point to a valid object and has indeterminate value because it was not initialized.

```
int *p;
*p =var-1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to have p point to an integer value with no memory allocated, you can't have this. p needs to point to an existing variable of type `int` which has the value var - 1. You could do something like this, using a temp variable to allocate space for var - 1.

```
    int var = 10;
    int temp = var - 1;
    int* p = &temp;
    printf("%d",*p);
```

or you could edit var directly.

```
    int var = 10;
    var -= 1;
    int* p = &var;
    printf("%d",*p);
```

Comment: Note that the outcome of the last snippet is the same even if the 2nd and 3rd line are swapped.

Answer (score 1):

You can't point to a *value*, you can only point to an *object* containing a value.  Remember that a pointer is an address<sup>1</sup>, and only objects can have addresses.

You can do one of two things:

- You can point `p` to `var`, then subtract  `1` from `var`:

  ```
  int var = 10;
  int *p = &var;
  *p = *p - 1; // same as writing var = var - 1
  printf( "%d\n", *p );
  ```

  This changes the value stored in `var`.

  If you don't want to change the value stored in `var`, then you need create a new object to store the value of `var - 1` and set `p` to point to this new object:

  ```
  int var = 10; 
  int var2 = var - 1; 
  int *p = var2;
  printf( "%d\n", *p );
  ```

---

1. Whether that's a virtual or physical address, whether it's a simple integral value or a tuple like (page # : offset), etc., is up to the implementation.